# Organizing data of different structure into a list of tuples with zip

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, tuples

Consider the following data:

```
x = [(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4)] 
y = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want to achieve the following structure:

```
[(1,1,1,'a'),(2,2,2,'b'),(3,3,3,'c'),(4,4,4,'d')]
```

For now, I am doing this:

```
zip(*zip(*x),y)
```

I would like to know if there some standard solution for the exposed problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't actually work in Python 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 13 2017, 10:15:16) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = [(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4)] 
>>> y = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> zip(*zip(*x),y)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

... although it does in Python 3, thanks to [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Compatibility aside, it's pretty opaque. A more straightforward list comprehension makes it clearer what you're doing:

```
[a + (b,) for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

... and works across Python versions.

As a side benefit, it's also about 70% faster than the nested zip approach, according to some quick, dirty testing on my machine.

Comment: What!!! In fact, in may example was a little different from what I really did.
I did `zip(y,*zip(*x))`, and this works.

Comment: Yes, that will work because your positional argument is *before* the `*` expression, rather than *after* it. This fragility is another reason to avoid your original approach, IMO.